# Media Upload not working after hiding some elements from functions.php

Tags: customization, uploads, admin-css

I have put the below code in **functions.php**. (It's used to hide some options from client.) But the problem is, after adding these codes, images are not uploading, can't even even uploaded photos from library or while creating a new post. Someone pls help

```
echo '<style> 
        #toplevel_page_wpcf7, #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo,  #screen-meta-links, #menu-tools, #wp-admin-bar-wpseo-menu, #footer-upgrade, #toplevel_page_wpfront-user-role-editor-all-roles,#toplevel_page_vc-general, #menu-settings,#toplevel_page_wpseo_dashboard, #toplevel_page_revslider, #toplevel_page_themepunch-google-fonts,#menu-appearance, #wp-admin-bar-snap-post, .error
        {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>';
```

Comment: What happens if you remove it?!

Comment: Of course it will work

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this code:-

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'myCssCode', PHP_INT_MAX);
function myCssCode() {
    ?>
    <style> 
        #toplevel_page_wpcf7, 
        #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo,
        #screen-meta-links,
        #menu-tools,
        #wp-admin-bar-wpseo-menu,
        #footer-upgrade,
        #toplevel_page_wpfront-user-role-editor-all-roles,
        #toplevel_page_vc-general,
        #menu-settings,
        #toplevel_page_wpseo_dashboard,
        #toplevel_page_revslider,
        #toplevel_page_themepunch-google-fonts,
        #menu-appearance,
        #wp-admin-bar-snap-post,
        .error
        {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: haven't tried that, but my code worked

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_css' );
    function admin_css(){ ?>
         <style> 
                    #toplevel_page_wpcf7, #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo,  #screen-meta-links, #menu-tools, #wp-admin-bar-wpseo-menu, #footer-upgrade, #toplevel_page_wpfront-user-role-editor-all-roles,#toplevel_page_vc-general, #menu-settings,#toplevel_page_wpseo_dashboard, #toplevel_page_revslider, #toplevel_page_themepunch-google-fonts,#menu-appearance, #wp-admin-bar-snap-post, .error
                    {
                        display:none;
                    }
                    </style>
    <?php
    }
```

this one worked